# PhantomJSDriver/GhostDriver slow to quit

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

Using this code I'm recording a consistent time of 12 seconds to quit PhantomJSDriver:

```
var driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

sw.Start();
driver.Quit(); // More specifically Dispose() is the bottleneck.
sw.Stop();

var time = sw.Elapsed;
```

In contrast InternetExplorerDriver, ChromeDriver and FirefoxDriver take 1 second (or less) to quit.

Using: selenium webdriver v2.39, phantomjs v1.9.2, win7 x64. Let me know if there is any other info I can provide.

**Edit:**
As a workaround for my purposes I could perform Quit() asynchronously to reduce the detriment when running multiple tests.

```
var task = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => { driver.Quit(); });
task.Start();
```

But it would be nice to fix this.